# How to install Networkit python in windows?

Tags: python, pip, g++, networkit

In order to install networkit... I tried

```
pip install networkit
```

But it threw error ....

```
ERROR: No suitable compiler found. Install any of these:  ['g++', 'g++-8', 'g++-7', 'g++-6.1', 'g++-6', 'g++-5.3', 'g++-5.2', 'g++-5.1', 'g++-5', 'g++-4.9', 'g++-4.8', 'clang++', 'clang++-3.8', 'clang++-3.7']
```

I then thought of directly running source code of networkit. So i downloaded it from [Networkit](https://pypi.org/project/networkit/#files)  and ran `python setup.py install`

But all this throwing same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/networkit/networkit#requirements lists following as requirements:

```
* A modern C++ compiler, e.g.: g++ (>= 4.8) or clang++ (>= 3.7)
* OpenMP for parallelism (usually ships with the compiler)
* Python3 (3.4 or higher is recommended, 3.3 supported)
* Pip
* CMake version 3.5 or higher (e.g., pip3 install cmake)
* Build system: Make or Ninja
* Cython version 0.21 or higher (e.g., pip3 install cython)
```

Error you see is saying that python setup cannot locate any c++ compilers.

Depending on on your platform, you need to install at least working compiler and cmake - how/what, depends on your os/distribution.

Comment: what should i do for installing compiler? Rest other requirements are present with me....

Comment: @TrickOrTreat **how/what, depends on your os/distribution** - you could try `apt install build-essential cmake` for starters assuming you are running something similar to debian ..

Comment: i have installed cmake already for windows. Not sure about debian.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers might help.. or you could try searching if you can find python wheel package somewhere to avoid compiling in your local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Networkit is not supported on native windows (yet).

If you are on windows 10 ,you can get WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) and install Networkit in it , see the said info and installation steps [here](https://networkit.github.io/get_started.html)

BTW,you will get the error of (no compiler found) even if you actually have a suitable compiler installed , this is because the script (setup.py) is really not intended for native windows yet, see the updated (setup.py) [here](https://github.com/ahmad-ra/networkit) to get the sense of how far it is from running on native windows